How to sync data from quickbooks to salesforce
I'm currently in the process of exploring various options to sync data from QuickBooks Online to Salesforce. Ideally, we're looking for free solutions if they exist.
We see some Salesforce plugins, but there seems to be a charge. As this is for a non-profit organization, we would like to reduce the cost as much as possible.
I would appreciate any pointers you could give me.
I am considering to give a try to DBSync - Integration for QuickBooks but I assume there will be some costs as well.

I think it will be helpful if you clarify what the end goal is. I talk to a lot of NonProfits who want to integrate SF and QBO and as we dive in and keep asking "Why?", sometimes there's not a great business case. This is particularly true for donation based non-profits.
The exception is social enterprises, i.e. non-profits that issue Invoices. There you'll find a great use case. But if this is for donations, I strongly recommend you do not integrate SF and QBO, and instead integrate SF with your donation system and just leave QBO to handle tax and accounting.
Also, keep in mind there will be a cost no matter what. Are you working for free to build a custom integration? Great! That's Free like a puppy is Free. Are you going to volunteer there forever? If not, who will maintain it? Who will provide support? Who will make updates when either QBO or SF changes something?

Thank you, @StonyGrunow. You are right that there will be some costs. The non-profit wanted to incur as little as possible.

Do they already have Invoices in QBO? Or are they going to be manually or automatically creating Invoices in QBO?
When we see NfPs try to use automation to create Invoices when they aren't already doing so manually, this is an integration red flag for us (if that helps!)
